# Where does one ask questions about a specific programming problem?

Tags: discussion, bug, site-rec

I'm working on refactoring some legacy c++ code.  I ran into a problem moving from a linked-list to using a vector.  Even though it seems straight forward (list is created once, and looped through many times), the conversion is proving anything but straight forward.  I made the mistake of thinking it was a SW-engineering question, and was rewarded -4 on my rep while being told to post it somewhere else.  Unfortunately, I don't see a good fit anywhere else.

So where would one post such a question.  It would seem that "programming.stackexchange.com" would be a valid place, but that mistakenly redirects to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com -- where programming questions are dissuaded.

So where should one post such a question?

At the very least, it seems akin to "entrapment" for programming to redirect to SWeng, if programming questions are out-of-place.  Why would someone setup  programming questions to be redirected to a forum where they will only get marked down and be judged as not appropriate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are implementation and debugging questions off-topic on Software Engineering?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/why-are-implementation-and-debugging-questions-off-topic-on-software-engineering)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a question about a specific programming problem or tools commonly used by programmers, the right place to post this is on Stack Overflow. See their description of [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [how to create good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I took a look at your question - it seemed OK in its current state, so I migrated it to Stack Overflow for you.

You're correct in that programmers.stackexchange.com now redirects to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, but the scope of the site has not significantly changed in several years. We changed our name from Programmers to Software Engineering (and our subdomain along with the name) to better reflect [our scope, which is documented in our Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The redirect is in place to ensure that links that may have been posted to questions here aren't broken and people can get to relevant questions and answers. Questions about writing or debugging code have never been on-topic here and have always belonged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you have a few moments can you chime in [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348376/why-is-my-1-question-being-marked-down-instantly). I'm totally confused what actually happened between your migration and it showing up on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @rene here is [noredirect original](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/347728/how-to-convert-linked-list-to-c-vector-why-doesnt-this-code-work?noredirect=1) of the question that was migrated from here to SO. Comment in there refers prior question from where it was reposted (it was deleted by OP - [10K link](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/347725)). Per my reading of [this MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348376) it is most likely that OP were posting their 2nd question thinking they are at SO...

Comment: ...though there is also a chance that they posted here instead of SO purposely for "training / learning" ([it's a known trick](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7610/31260))

Comment: Thanks @gnat for clarifying a bit of the confusion and I feel sorry for you guys to have to deal with the training/learning trick ....