# Understanding the guidelines

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently asked [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340606/) about a specific term (JTNU) that I saw in a job posting.

After seeing the downvotes, I read:

[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-software-engineering-previously-known-as-programmers-a-guide-for)

https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq/info

And I didn't find it to be off topic since it was related a term in a job posting and searching for [non-jtnu](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=meaning%20Non%2DJNTU) didn't yield good things on google.

The [info](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/terminology/info) for the terminology tag reads:

> Questions about the objective meaning or common understanding of words and concepts that programmers encounter

We are in a field where a new acronym pops up each week. So, I thought I was behind and it would be reasonable to ask such question.

I know now that it is an Indian University whose degrees doesn't seem to be great. But when I first searched and saw the university I didn't think it was related.

**Isn't it a valid terminology question since it appears in job posts?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, the tag info could have have been interpreted that way when taking it literally. However, I am very sure the community here does not want an interpretation like

> Questions about the objective meaning or common understanding of **arbitrary** words and concepts that programmers encounter

This site's scope today is about the [systems development life cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) - one action to make this more clear was the site name change last year. Abbreviations in job offers, especially when it turns out they are just an abbreviation for a university somewhere in the world, are - to my understanding - too localized and not related to the SDLC.

So I took your question as a chance for improvement, and changed the tag description to make it better fit to the actual site's scope.